# How to check for difference in previous and next value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Was working with the code below for sending a list of values to another component -

```
React.createElement("ul", null,
  this.state.stock.map(function (value){
    return (React.createElement(Price, { price: value })) 
  })
)
```

and then the values will be sent to the component below -

```
var initialPrice = null;
var iconClass = ' ';
var counter = 0;
var Price = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var newPrice = this.props.price.l_fix;
    var finalPrice = newPrice - initialPrice;

    if(finalPrice < 0) {
      iconClass = 'bg-danger glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom text-danger';
    }
    else if(finalPrice > 0) {
      iconClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top text-success bg-success';
    }

    initialPrice = newPrice;

    return (
      React.createElement("li", null, this.props.price.t," ( ",this.props.price.e,"  ) -  "," Current Price : ",this.props.price.l_fix,"   ",  
                         React.createElement("span", { className: iconClass, "aria-hidden": "true" }),"      Date : ",this.props.price.lt)
                )
        }
    });
```

In the above component there is one problem. If I am sending a single value then the conditions are working fine. But, if I use a list of values then the conditions are not working correctly. Checking for last and next values for displaying the triangle arrow top and bottom. While rendering the result, when doing the calculation the values are not getting properly calculated. Is there any way to calculate the values correctly and then show the correct result for every item in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method for this. It receives `nextProps` as the parameter, and can access current props by  `this.props`.

Here is method description:

> Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState() within this function will not trigger an additional render.

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9zbrxtx/9/) with an example similar to your case, so you can see how it works. I pass props with a components within an interval, and see the dynamics in comparison with previous state:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    let dynamics = ['=', '=']
    
    for(let i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(i)
      if (nextProps.values[i] > this.props.values[i]) {
        dynamics[i] = '+'
      } 
      else if (nextProps.values[i] === this.props.values[i]) {
        dynamics[i] = '='
      } 
      else {
        dynamics[i] = '-'
      }
    }
```

Hope, you will adept it for your case without any problems.

Comment: Thanks @Lazarev Alexandr, will try to make it.

Comment: you have taken only two values in the fiddler. Have 'n' values in the main problem. How to get the total number of times that will be calling for loop. I tried using `(this.props).length`  but it didn't work out. Any other solutions ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k9zbrxtx/8/ Here you go, should use `this.props.values.length` or `nextProps.values.length`

Answer (score 0):

componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated along with componentWillMount and componentWillUpdate.
Use getderivedStateFromProps(nextProps, preState) 
just be careful as this lifecycle method is static and is invoked when your component is instantiated.